# How can I index this csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am writing code for a project that will parse METARs (hourly weather reports at airports). I am attempting to use a csv file (see the end of post). I am wondering where my code is faulty as I am getting an error. I am thinking it is something with my array but I cannot figure out where.
**My Code**

```
from time import sleep
import os
import pandas as pd
os.getcwd()
os.chdir('/home/pi/wmap')

i=2
while i==2:
    n=0
    t12=pd.read_csv('mtr.csv', usecols = ['ASOS'])
    iad_metars = MetarSet('t12[n]')
    iad_metars.refresh()
    latest_iad_metars = iad_metars.get_latest()
    #print(latest_iad_metars.raw_text)
    print(latest_iad_metars.station)#prints latest city ID
    print(latest_iad_metars.temp) #runs temperature
    print(latest_iad_metars.dewpoint)
    #print(latest_iad_metars.winds)
    print(latest_iad_metars.visibility)
    #print(latest_iad_metars.cloud_layers)
    n=n+1
    print("******\n")
    sleep(15)
    if n==26:
        n=0
```

The error I receive is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "map.py", line 11, in <module>
    t12=pd.read_csv('mtr.csv', usecols = ['ASOS'])
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 688, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 454, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 948, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1180, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 2056, in __init__
    _validate_usecols_names(usecols, self.orig_names)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1305, in _validate_usecols_names
    f"Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: {missing}"
ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: ['ASOS']


------------------
(program exited with code: 1)
Press return to continue
```

**CSV**
KCAR    0
KBOS    1
KALB    2
KJFK    3
KBWI    4
KCLT    5
KCHS    6
KATL    7
KMCO    8
KMIA    9
KMSY    10
KIAH    11
KDFW    12
KOUN    13
KOMA    14
KORD    15
KMSP    16
KCVG    17
KSTL    18
KBIS    19
KUNR    20
KABQ    21
KPHX    22
KLAS    23
KSAN    24
KSFO    25
KSEA    26

Comment: The table is not posting properly, so the KXXX fields are on the first column and the 0-26 are on the other side (to light up an led)

Comment: try importing without the `usecols` param, then select cols of interest from dataframe with `df[[your list of column names]]`

Comment: How would I do that, I am a bit lost...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is throwing an error on line 11, where you try to import the file `mtr.csv` with the pandas `read_csv` method and usecols param. The ValueError thrown says that the column header ASOS wasn't found.

An alternative would be to import using the default params then select your column of interest, like I mentioned in my comment above.

```py
t12 = pd.read_csv('mtr.csv')
t12 = t12[['ASOS']]
```